# expo-location sometimes not getting location updates when phone is locked

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, geolocation

I have an application that works like a fitness tracker. The user starts recording a path, locks the phone and puts it in a pocket. After a few minutes the phone is unlocked and the path is expected to have been recorded.

This works for most users but in some cases it seems that locations is only tracked when the phone is not locked. So if the user unlocks the phone a few times while recording you can see these points in the result afterwards, but between the points where the phone was unlocked there are no points at all.

I can not recreate this issue on an iPhone 11 but it appears on an iPhone 13 pro for instance. I am looking for suggestions on how to recreate this issue as I don't know what is causing it.

This is how I start the foreground task that is tracking the location:

```
        await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(TRACKING_BACKGROUND_TASK, {
          distanceInterval: 1,
          accuracy: LocationAccuracy.BestForNavigation,
          activityType: Location.LocationActivityType.OtherNavigation,
          foregroundService: {
            notificationTitle: "App name",
            notificationBody: "Tracking",
          },
        });
```

Before that I have requested foreground permissions:

```
Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync()
```

This is my foreground task:

```
  TaskManager.defineTask(
    TRACKING_BACKGROUND_TASK,
    (body: TaskManager.TaskManagerTaskBody<object>) => {
      if (body.error) {
        console.error(body.error.message);
        return;
      }

      const data = body.data as unknown as { locations: LocationObject[] };

      const locations = data?.locations;

      if (!locations) {
        return;
      }

      for (const location of locations) {
        for (const callback of Object.values(locationCallbacks)) {
          callback(location);
        }
      }
    }
  );
```

I don't think that there are so many things to configure, this is quite straight forward so I don't know what to try. Is there any external circumstances that could possibly be the source to this issue?

Comment: It's important that  iOS granted location access permission  to be `ALWAYS` therefore permission is granted even if app is not focused/active.

Comment: Is it possible to request for ALWAYS without requesting for background permissions?

Comment: @FistonEmmanuel for what its worth, I don't necessarily think that you are correct in that assumption. I think that WHEN IN USE should be enough. Any source?

Comment: WHEN IN USE is valuable when the app is in the foreground. Apple is clear for this - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/handling_location_updates_in_the_background

Comment: So what is the use for a foreground service? It does not require background permissions. I think a foreground service is running when the phone is locked even though it does not need background permissions. Why even bother existing as a service if not?

Comment: Technically, you don't need foreground service on iOS.